# Getting two DataFields from SQL into the Text of a dropdownlist

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to make it so that I can get two pieces of data from SQL Server into the `Text Field` of a `drop down list`. So if I get the data `AccountID='1','2'` and `CompanyName='Build it inc','It ltd'`. I want it to display:

1-Build it inc

2-It ltd

I can get the data from sql and get the `DataValueField` to `AccountID` but how do I display it. Here is my aspx.

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DDLTemplates" DataValueField="AccountID" 
   DataTextField='<%#Eval("AccountID") + "-" + Eval("CompanyName")%>' 
   runat="server"></asp:DropDownList>
```

How do I do this?

Edit: Since alot of you are asking here is my code behind. Thanks for all the Help

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {

        DDLTemplates.DataSource = GetItems();
        DDLTemplates.DataBind();
    }

}
public DataSet GetItems()
{
    String conn = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["LiquidusConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
    SqlConnection sqlConnection2 = new SqlConnection(conn);
    string oString = "Select AccountID, CompanyName from Account";
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(oString);
    cmd.Connection = sqlConnection2;
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    sqlConnection2.Open();
    da.Fill(ds);
    sqlConnection2.Close();
    return ds;
}
```

Answer Edit: psoshmo and ragerory Have found the Answer to my question. Here is my code now that it works:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DDLTemplates" DataValueField="AccountID" DataTextField="Company" runat="server"></asp:DropDownList>
```

Code Behind:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {

        DDLTemplates.DataSource = GetItems();
        DDLTemplates.DataBind();
    }

}
public DataSet GetItems()
{
    String conn = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["LiquidusConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
    SqlConnection sqlConnection2 = new SqlConnection(conn);
    string oString = "SELECT AccountID, (Convert(varchar,AccountId) + ' - ' + CompanyName) as company FROM Account";
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(oString);
    cmd.Connection = sqlConnection2;
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    sqlConnection2.Open();
    da.Fill(ds);
    sqlConnection2.Close();
    return ds;
}
```

Hope this helps future googler's :)

Comment: Why not create a field that already has the concatenation and apply that to your DataTextField? You're binding the control to an object and making AccountId your value field, do the same thing for your TextField except do the string concatenation on the back on the property.

Comment: Sorry, im new to programming and alot of what you said didnt click. By any chance do you have a link or example?

Comment: Can you post the code you have that is getting "AccountId" and "CompanyName"? It will be easier to show you that way.

Comment: Yes, I have just edited it in thank you!

Comment: @vmedhe2 I have just edited my answer with some advice, I would consider setting up classes to hold methods like GetItems() so you do not have to duplicate your code as you website grows. It also is a good practice to keep database connections from living inside of your interface. just some food for thought :)

Comment: Okay, Thanks I will start reading up on the subject

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your `GetItems` method, you can change the `oString` variable...

```
string oString = "SELECT AccountID, (Convert(varchar,AccountId) + ' - ' + CompanyName) as Company FROM Account";
```

And then change your control to the following

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DDLTemplates" DataValueField="AccountID" DataTextField="Company" runat="server"></asp:DropDownList>
```

You're concatenating the two fields and making them one column called `Company` so that's what you should have as the TextField.

Comment: Sorry that was a bad edit from something I tried that did not work. I have reedited to show what it originally was.

Comment: Hi, I tried this and I get the Error, "Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'Master Account' to data type int". I am not sure what "Master Account" is. Its not a column in the Account table.

Comment: @vmedhe2 "SELECT AccountID, (Convert(varchar,AccountId) + ' - ' + CompanyName) as Company FROM Account"                       try that

Comment: Yeah, you're trying to concatenate an `int` and a `varchar`. `Master Account` is a value in your CompanyName column, and since the first value in the concatenation is `AccountId` (I'm assuming int), it's trying to apply the rest as int. Do what @psoshmo said above and your issue should be resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Simply Create a field in your class that adds these together, and bind that to the DataTextField

something like:

```
public string YourFieldNameHere
{
  get { return String.Format("{0} - {1}", AccountID, CompanyName); }

}
```

EDIT: My bad for assuming you had a class file setup. In general, you should avoid having methods like GetItems() in your code for the web page. If you have to get those same records in another page, you will end up duplicating your code, which is bad practice. I would recommend you consider setting up class files to handle select statements like this, as well as other fields and methods you may need.

Comment: Anyone who wants to do this is going to need to know what class they are adding this code to, and how to add the code so it does not get deleted the next time the class is generated.

Comment: @Trisped yes you are correct, I was perhaps assuming too much. He needs to have a class file with the partial keyword if he wants to be able to define these kind of things, as well as methods. I assume he know whats class hes referring to though...

Comment: @psoshmo I'm curious why you say the class needs to be partial for just adding a field to an entity...

Comment: @ragerory I could be wrong, but that is how I have always done it. Setting up a class file marked partial with all my select methods, properties like the one were discussing here, etc. I am no expert though, so if there is an easier way I am open to suggestions :)

Comment: @psoshmo partial classes end up boiling down on the CLR as one class. If you have things that need to be separated, just use separate classes. Partials are better used if you have one part of the class that is always being updated (lets say by a code generator), and you want to extend that class but not have it overwritten, use the partial keyword somewhere so it's still part of that class. That's one example but just to separate parts of it doesn't really make sense in practice.

Comment: @ragerory Sorry I was going off of what Trisped said, Where the class was being auto generated. I may not have been clear. But yes, it would be strange to use partial to seperate things just for the sake of seperating them

Comment: @psoshmo ah, ok. Yeah, *if* the class was being generated then yes, but there isn't a reason to assume that at this point, so not sure why that was brought up.

Comment: @ragerory hehe fair enough :)